# Extract variables from string with Regex

Tags: regex, scala

I'm trying to extract from a string variables with the following format: ${var}

Given this string:

```
val s = "This is a string with ${var1} and ${var2} and {var3}"
```

The result should be

```
List("var1","var2")
```

This is the attempt, it ends in an exception. What's wrong with this regex?

```
val pattern = """\${([^\s}]+)(?=})""".r
val s = "This is a string with ${var1} and ${var2} and {var3}"
val vals = pattern.findAllIn(s)

println(vals.toList)
```

and the exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException:
>
> Illegal repetition near index 1 `\${([^\s}]+)(?=})`

Comment: Your code has the regex as `\${([^\s}]+)(?=})` but the error shows `/${([^/s}]+)(?=})` - both the slashes are different, shows forward `/` in the error.

Comment: it was a typo, I fixed the exception

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**NOTE** :- `{` in regex have special meaning. It denotes range. e.g. `a{2,10}` denotes match `a` in between `2` to `10` times. So you need to escape `{`.

**Solution 1**

```
val pattern = """\$\{([^\s}]+)(?=})""".r
```

You need to access the first capturing group for finding the result and then change it to list.

**Solution 2**

You can also use lookbehind like

```
val pattern = """(?<=\$\{)[^\s}]+(?=})""".r
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/gcdAG4)**